# How to make base64 print the encoded output after a newline without newline being encoded?

Tags: stdin, base64

I like to encode with `base64` from stdin by invoking the command pasting the input and pressing <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> twice in order to avoid a trailing newline if I don't want one to be part of the input. It avoids `echo` and leaves no data in the shell history.

However, the output is written directly after the input and it's hard to retrieve the value:

```
$ base64
Input without trailing newlineSW5wdXQgd2l0aG91dCB0cmFpbGluZyBuZXdsaW5l
```

Is there any way I can look like

```
$ base64
Input without trailing newline
SW5wdXQgd2l0aG91dCB0cmFpbGluZyBuZXdsaW5l
```

without any newlines being included in the encoded output?

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a a little shell `alias` that should do what you want:

```
alias b64='x="$(base64)"; echo; echo "$x"'
```

Simply run `b64` and do what you suggest in the OP.

Comment: Also added `alias b64-decode='x="$(base64 --decode)"; echo; echo "$x"'`